# HeavisideTheta does not simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The command

```
FullSimplify[HeavisideTheta[x a], Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

should return

```
HeavisideTheta[x]
```

but it does not.

Comment: Is there a typo?: "should not return" or "should return"? -- Also, consider `D[HeavisideTheta[x a], x]` vs. `D[HeavisideTheta[x], x]`

Comment: `HeavisideTheta` is the implementation in MMA of a distribution, not a usual function `UnitStep`. As Michae lE2 noticed in his comment, its properties differ from properties of a usual function.

Comment: However you define it,     HeavisideTheta[ a x ] =  HeavisideTheta[x]    whenever a > 0. Mathematica is unable to infer this simple fact.

Comment: Even UnitStep which is well defined at the origin also does not simplify.

Comment: " `HeavisideTheta[ a x ] = HeavisideTheta[x]` whenever `a > 0`". This is not true (see Properties in [Weki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Dirac+delta+function&title=Special%3ASearch&ns0=1) for info).

Comment: There is some inconsistency: `FullSimplify[HeavisideTheta[2 x]]` evaluates to `HeavisideTheta[x]`.

Answer (score 1):

As various comments point out, `HeavisideTheta` isn't a function in the mathematical sense.  It should not simplify as such because

```
Derivative[1][HeavisideTheta][a x]
```

returns `DiracDelta[a x]`, and this is certainly different from `DiracDelta[x]`.

### Experiments with various expressions

`HeavisideTheta@0` remains unevaluated.  I think that's part of the issue, so

```
Simplify[HeavisideTheta[x a], Assumptions->{a>0,x>0}]
```

returns 1, and for `x<0` returns 0.

---

`UnitStep@0` is defined.  Still, I need to suggest to Mathematica the result:

```
Simplify[Reduce[UnitStep[x a] == UnitStep[x]], Assumptions->a>0]
```

returns True.

---

Mathematica seems to like the explicit piecewise definition more:

```
Simplify[Piecewise@{{0,#<0}, {1,True}} &[a x], Assumptions->a>0]
```

returns Piecewise@{{0,x<0}, {1,True}}

Comment: `HeavisideTheta` is the implementation in MMA of a distribution, not a usual function `UnitStep`.

Comment: Regardless, it should obey obvious properties.

Comment: It should only obey true statements. Conditions for distributions can be made only outside of the evaluation integrals, because distributions are integral kernels with unspecified algebra of restriction or transformation maps: '###Theta[ a x ] [ f ] =Integrate[f[x],{ a x, 0, Infinity}].  ### There exist no rules for range transformations of  such complex line integrals.